# Set width of one div based on another

Tags: jquery, css, width

I've got the following problem. I need to set a width of one div every time user clicks on anchor. Width of this div should be taken from another div. How to achieve this?

Following code doesn't work (please keep in mind, that script is wrapped inside PHP echo):

```
jQuery(".geother").click(function(){
var pos=$("p.second").width() + "px";
jQuery("#headerRightContactPhone span").css(\'width\', pos);
}
```

Edit (I also would need another thing, I'd like to apply to "geother" div CSS left, which would be negative value of pos width+230px):

```
jQuery(".geother").click(function(){
   var pos = $("p.second").width(); // don't need to use 'px'
   jQuery("#headerRightContactPhone span").css('width', pos); // don't need escaping
   $(this).css('left', ((230+pos)*-1) );
});
```

Comment: I just never ever use span; should be deprecated in a few years, I hope...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery(".geother").click(function(){
   var pos = $("p.second").width(); // don't need to use 'px'
   jQuery("#headerRightContactPhone span").css('width', pos); // don't need escaping
}); //  you missed ');' here
```

#### Note

You should need to give `display: block` to your `span` or use any block element like `div`, `p` etc.

```
jQuery(".geother").click(function(){
       var pos = $("p.second").width(); // don't need to use 'px'
       jQuery("#headerRightContactPhone span").css({
                     width: pos, 
                     display: 'block',
                     left: '-' + (230+pos)
               }); // don't need escaping
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer works very well. I've also edited the first post, because I need another small modification. Could you take a look ?

Answer (score 3):

Are you applying a width to a span element? This is the problem then. Make the span a block or use a div.

Comment: A <span> is an inline element and does not have an implicit "width" attribute.

Comment: Adding clarification as to "why" you can't add a width to a span.